# d3.csv function can not load data correctly

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use d3.csv load iris.csv data then make a scatterplot. But the data is empty when I use debugger look inside the data.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var outerWidth = 300;
var outerHeight = 250;
var rMin = 5; // "r" stands for radius
var rMax = 20;
var xColumn = "sepal_length";
var yColumn = "petal_length";
var rColumn = "sepal_width";

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", outerWidth)
  .attr("height", outerHeight);

var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, outerWidth]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([outerHeight, 0]);
var rScale = d3.scale.linear().range([rMin, rMax]);

function render(data) {
  xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d[xColumn]; }));
  yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d[yColumn]; }));
  rScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){ return d[rColumn]; }));

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
  circles.enter().append("circle");
  circles
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d[yColumn]); })
    .attr("r",  function(d){ return rScale(d[rColumn]); });

  circles.exit().remove();
}

function type(d) {
  d.sepal_length = +d.sepal_length;
  d.sepal_width = +d.sepal_width;
  d.petal_length = +d.petal_length;
  d.petal_width = +d.petal_width;
}

d3.csv("iris.csv", type, render);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the csv file:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,class
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
```

[Here is the the picture for debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnU6a.png)

[And here is the picture for iris.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4d3S.png)

Can someone help me figure out what's went wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the plain text of your code and at least 10 lines of your iris.csv file. Thanks

Comment: @Klaujesi, I already added code and csv file, please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, because I didn't verify it:

Your `type` function does not return anything.
According to [the d3 CSV description](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#csv), the second method of `d3.csv()` is called the "accessor"-method:

> An optional accessor function may be specified, which is then passed to d3.csv.parse

The documentation of [csv.parse()](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) says this:

> An optional accessor function may be specified as the second argument. This function is invoked for each row in the CSV file, being passed the current row and index as two arguments. The return value of the function replaces the element in the returned array of rows; if the function returns null, the row is stripped from the returned array of rows

So I suppose that because of nothing is returned by `type`, the element is removed from the list and this is why you have 0 results. If you would `return d;` it could work.

Again, it's just a guess by looking at the documentation, maybe I'm totally wrong. If this didn't help, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is based off of a tutorial by Curran Kelleher? I was also having trouble with this exercise since there have been a few updates to d3 since he made the tutorial. I got stuck on the last bit of code:

```
d3.csv("iris.csv", type, render);
```

in d3 version 5, that will not work. They are now doing

```
d3.csv("iris.csv").then(render)
```

More information can be found at https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with `D3js` version `v4`. The way of using data parsed by `d3.csv` looks like

```
d3.csv("/path/data/mydata.csv", function(data) {
   console.log(data[0]); // print out the first row of the data
});
```